# Query to find value in column dependent on a different column in table being the minimum date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset that looks like this. I would like to pull a distinct id, the minimum date and value on the minimum date.

```
id  date         value
1   01/01/2020  0.5
1   02/01/2020  1
1   03/01/2020  2
2   01/01/2020  3
2   02/01/2020  4
2   03/01/2020  5
```

This code will pull the id and the minimum date

```
select Distinct(id), min(nav_date)
from table
group by id
```

How can I get the value on the minimum date so the output of my query looks like this?

```
id  date    value
1   01/01/2020  0.5
2   01/01/2020  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from t
order by id, date;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(id, date)` and is typically the fastest way to do this operation in Postgres.